# How to make nested list from three table?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have three tables like below:

```
[Category]->[SubCategory]->[Leaf]

-> means one-to-many relation;
```

Is it possible to make nested list with just one query?

Actual Query:

```
Select * from Category
join SubCategory
join Leaf
```

Intended Output:

```
Category
--Subcategory
----Leaf
----Leaf
--Subcategory
----Leaf
----Leaf
```

I know about composite design pattern; but lets say I have the result set from query and I want to manipulate the list above with minimal attempt.

**Update**

My question is without for loop and sub query, can it be done with the one query above, or what is the best way to generate 3 nested list like above from three tables?

**Update**:

What is the most optimized way to create a nested list like above from three tables in any database and in any language?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `$tree[$category][$subcategory][] = $leaf;`?

Comment: when you creating list, check the IDs and seperate according to same IDs in result..

Comment: Your question is still vague. " can it be done with the one query above" -- if it's about mysql (?) then remove `php` tag and ask a question about `mysql`

Comment: my question is a algorithm question, not mysql question; read the question again!

Comment: what is the best optimized way to create a list from three tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Category c
JOIN SubCategory s ON s.CategoryID = c.ID
JOIN Leaf l ON l.SubCategoryID = s.ID
ORDER BY c.ID, s.ID, l.ID
```

Then in your PHP loop, print the Category name whenever it changes, print the SubCategory name whenever it changes, and print every Leaf name.

```
$last_cat = null;
while ($row = fetch()) {
    if ($row['CategoryName'] !== $last_cat) {
        echo $row['CategoryName'] . "\n";
        $last_cat = $row['CategoryName'];
        $last_subcat = null;
    }
    if ($row['SubCategoryName'] != $last_subcat) {
        echo "--{$row['SubCategoryName']}\n";
        $last_subcat = $row['SubCategoryName'];
    }
    echo "----{$row['LeafName']\n";
}
```

Comment: this was my first approach, but is there any easier way?

Comment: How much easier could it get? There's hardly any code there. There's no built-in method to print nested lists.